# Repeat forever but report each x seconds

Tags: python, benchmarking, timing

I'm trying to benchmark how many times a function is able to run in, say 10 seconds using this code:

```
import time

window = 10

while True:
    n = 0
    while time.time() % window:
        test()      # which really runs only a fragment of a second
        n = n + 1
    print "n: %s" % n
```

But `test()` keeps running over and over without me seeing any output (*way* longer than 10 seconds).  I understand that the `time.time() % window` is probably naive but I can't come up with the right way.

Could anybody push me in the right direction?  I'd like to avoid "real benchmarking tools" in favor of learning how to do it.

Comment: If you wanted to use something a little more robust, check out [cProfile](http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-cProfile). I've used it for performance debugging before and it works well. Sorry, I just read the last part. I'll leave this here in case there are others that want to use "real benchmarking tools." :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does what I wanted (plus avoids the modulo jeopardy):

```
import time

def testFor(w, fn):
    n = 0
    start = time.time()
    while (time.time() - start) < w:
        fn()
        n = n + 1
    return n

window = 10

while True:
    n = testFor(window, test)
    print "n: %s" % n
```

Answer (score 0):

`time.time()` is returning a floating point representation of the time.

When you modulus it, you'll almost never have it return exactly 0.

Consider using: `int(time.time()) % window`

---

Heads up though: you'll want a sleep at the end of your loop to prevent running the outer loop multiple times per "benchmark".  You can avoid this by benchmarking time-per-X-iterations instead of iterations-per-X-time.

---

Rough example of time-per-X-iterations:

```
window = 1000
start = time.time()
n = 0

while True:
    test()
    n = n + 1

    if n % window == 0:
        print "Average: %f/sec" % ( n / (time.time() - start) )
```

Comment: I already tried `int(time.time()) % window` but that has the problem that it's true much more times than once in 10 seconds.

Comment: If you'd like to pursue that route, you can add a `while int(time.time()) % window == 0:  pass` after the print.